Can I save and load a list of variables in the Live Expressions tab in STM32CubeIDE without creating a new workspace?
I am using STM32CubeIDE Version: 1.15.0 for my development of various projects. When I open a new project, the previous project's debug variables are still in the Live Expressions tab of the Debug view and are irrelevant to the newly loaded project. Besides creating a new workspace for each project, is there another way to save or load a list of debug variables from/into the Live Expressions tab?
I did look in the Live Expressions tab and right clicked to see what options exist, but there seems to be nothing useful to save or load a variable list. I do expect to have such a feature as it can be quite frustrating to have to remove and then recreate the variables for different projects without creating a whole new workspace. Am I missing something here?
